# Template Constructor Taking Precedence Over Normal Copy and Move Constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11

The output of the following program...

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct X
{
    X(const X&)              { cout << "copy" << endl; }
    X(X&&)                   { cout << "move" << endl; }

    template<class T> X(T&&) { cout << "tmpl" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    X x1 = 42;
    X x2(x1);
}
```

is

```
tmpl
tmpl
```

The desired output is:

```
tmpl
copy
```

Why doesn't the concrete copy constructor take precedence over the template constructor?

Is there anyway to fix it so that the copy and move constructor overloads will take precedence over the template constructor?

Comment: Here is the final class relating to this question: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/20058/a-c11-any-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal overload resolution rules still apply when choosing the constructor - and a constructor taking a non-const lvalue reference (for the template constructor after argument deduction) is a better match than a constructor taking a const lvalue reference.

You could, of course, just add another overload taking a non-const lvalue reference, i.e.

```
X(X&)              { cout << "copy" << endl; }
```

**Update**: Other cases where the template constructor is a better match:

```
const X f()
{ return X(); }

struct Y : X
{ Y() { } };

int main()
{
  X x3(f()); // const-qualified rvalue
  Y y;
  X x4(y); // derived class
}
```

Comment: Do I also need to add `X(const X&&)` or is this impossible?  Are there any other cases where either the move or copy constructor would match in the abscence of the template constructor?

Comment: @AndrewTomazosFathomlingCorps: SFINAE can help you there, so that you can have both your function signature *intact* (I think that is important). For example, you can use `std::enable_if` in the function template to enable the desired cases only.

Comment: Yes, if you happen to have a const rvalue, e.g. from `const X f();` and `X x3(f())`. Then there is the case where the initializer is a derived class which would also use the template constructor.

Answer (score 6):

**Well, it is because of [reference-collapsing](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_08.html)**.

At the overload resolution stage, when the function template is instantiated, `T` is deduded to be `X&`, so `T&&` (which is `X& &&`) becomes `X&` due to reference-collapsing, and the instantiated function from the function template becomes *exact match* and the copy-constructor *requires* a conversion from `X&` to `const X&` (which is why it is not selected being *inferior match*).

However, if you remove the `const` from the copy-constructor, the copy-constructor will be preferred. Try this:

```
X(/*const*/ X&) { cout << "copy" << endl; }
```

[Output](http://ideone.com/wAOpyo) as expected.

Or alternatively, if you make the parameter in the function template as `const T&` then copy-constructor will be called (even if it remains same!), because reference-collapsing will not come into picture now:

```
template<class T> X(const T &) { cout << "tmpl" << endl; }
```

[Output](http://ideone.com/MvWoKB) is expected, again.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to add another constructor (as other answers suggested), you can use SFINAE to constrain the call, by replacing your template constructor by this:

```
template<class T
    , typename std::enable_if<not std::is_same<X, typename std::decay<T>::type>::value, int>::type = 0 
> X(T&&) { cout << "tmpl " << endl; }
```

Which just involves adding a `dummy` default template argument (a known technique: [Link](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html)). No extra headers are necessary.

You will get the desired output.

I got this answer from a related problem: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20141205121901/http://flamingdangerzone.com:80/cxx11/2012/06/05/is_related.html). All this looks rather inelegant, but seems to be the only way out for now. I still would like to see a more elegant solution.