# move and templated constructor, wrong one is taken

Tags: c++, move, forwarding-reference

I need to have a class which takes copy/move and a templated constructor like the following example:

```
    class A
{
    public:
    A() {}
    A( A&& ){std::cout << "Move" << std::endl;}
    A( const A& ){ std::cout << "copy" << std::endl;}

    template < typename T>
        A( T&& ) { std::cout << "any" << std::endl; }
};

class B: public A
{
    public:
    B():A() {}
    B( const B& b): A(b) {}
    B( B&& b): A( std::move(b)) {}
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    B b2( b );              // expected call copy
    B b3( std::move( b ));  // expected call to move

}
```

But I run into the templated constructor which is absolutely misterious to me. Why is the move constructor not the better match?

Found some hints here:  [Template Constructor Taking Precedence Over Normal Copy and Move Constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14100171/template-constructor-taking-precedence-over-normal-copy-and-move-constructor)

In one of the comments I see that SFINAE is taken a possibility. But I could not see any valid implementation to select the correct constructor. Can someone give me a hint to pick up the correct constructor?

I expect to go up the inheritance hierarchy with the move constructors. So how to implement the move constructors that the correct one of the base class will be chosen. As this I expect the output "move" here instead of "any".

EDIT:
In addition to the given answer the following solution seem also to work:

```
class B: public A
{    
    public:
        B():A() {}
        B( const B& b ): A( (const A&)b ) {}
        D( B&& b): A( std::forward<A>(b)) {}
};
```

That also explains why the template in the base class "eats" the constructor call, as the implicit cast from B to A is not needed for the template and so the template is the better match. If explicit casted before, all works fine.

Comment: the one that prints `"Move"` is not a move-constructor.. please include the output and the expected one, just to avoid misunderstandings

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818: quite clear... sorry fixed it

Comment: And please show us the output you get from running the program, and the output you *expect* to get.

Comment: @Klaus dont say sorry to me, but maybe to Nathan, it is his answer that now maybe has to be fixed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In

```
A( std::move(b))
```

`std::move(b)` gives you a `B&&`.  When overload resolution is performed it finds `A( A&& )` and (from the template) `A( B&& )`.  The template is an exact match, so it will chose that instead.

To fix this, just get rid of the template, you don't need it.  If you do need it in your actual code, then you can use SFINAE on the template constructor to stop it from being called by derived classes using

```
template < typename T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_convertible_v<T*, A*>, bool> = true>
A( T&& ) { std::cout << "any" << std::endl; }
```

Comment: But how can I write my move constructor so that the inheritance hierarchy will always take the move constructors as expected?

Comment: @Klaus Just added that.

Comment: Great. And if I want to use the copy constructor with `B b3(b)` I again run into any and not as expected into copy????

Comment: @Klaus Answer updated to use `is_convertible_v` to cover both scenarios.

Comment: Forget about... hacked a typo in... an addition & catches me :-) Thanks. But yes, would be nice to get some explanation why is_base_of will not work in that case. Thanks

Comment: @Klaus I'm trying to figure that out right now.  To me it should work, but I must be missing something.  Does the code as is work for you now?

Comment: Yes, changed my last comment! Sorry, was a typo as i experimented with the solution in comment from Storry Teller. Sorry for that!

Comment: @Klaus Okay, I've figure out the reason.  In `A(b)` `b` is a `B const &`.  As a reference, it is not derived from `A`.  So, to use `is_base_of` you need `std::is_base_of_v<A, std::remove_reference_t<T>>` so you get rid of the referenceness of `T`

Comment: Thank you. Got it!